# LayerSlider: Hide slide in the sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, slide

I am using LayerSlider plugin in Wordpress. 
I tried to use event callbacks to run custom code when certain actions occur in sliders like described in this [tutorial](http://docs.offlajn.com/layer-slider/39-advanced-customization/190-layerslider-api).
Is there a way to hide slide in the sequence.

I tried the below code where I want to jump to slide "4" based on condition but this didn't work (It still show all slides).

```
function( event, slider ) {
    if(slider.slides.current.index == 2){
        $('#slider').layerSlider(4);                
    }
}
```

Please any idea.

Comment: Have your tried adding a `console.log();`  into your `if()` condition to see if it ever returns true?

Comment: Yes I tried it before and after "$('#slider').layerSlider(4);" and it returns true but it didn't jump to slide 4.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? And have you tried to change `4`to a different slide? it's hard to offer a solution without the relevant source code or a working demo to debug and work with.

Comment: No there is no errors and I tried different slide but the same result. Unfortunately I didn't have a working demo :(